# Handling In Webdriver Using Chromeoptions

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing the error in chrome which is **"You Are Using An Unsupported Command-Line Flag –Ignore-Certificate-Errors. Stability And Security Will Suffer."** for my below selenium code.

```
Public Sub key()
  Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver  
  selenium.Start "chrome", "https://google.com/"
selenium.stop
End Sub
```

I have searched the same error solution in below link.

http://www.abodeqa.com/tag/how-to-remove-you-are-using-an-unsupported-command-line-flag-ignore-certificate-errors-stability-and-security-will-suffer/

Please explain how can i apply the answer mention in above link into my VBA code.

Comment: Please show us your code that sets up the Capabilities for your ChromeDriver.  This is where you are already setting up that flag.

Comment: `Please explain how can i apply the answer mention in above link into my VBA code.` If you want a VBA answer, why the VB.NET tag?

Answer (score 2):

I could not find documentation for SeleniumWrapper. So, I *assumed* that `SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver.Start` doesn't handle any `ChromeOptions' related arguments.

If the above assumption is true, one cannot apply [the given solution in C#](http://www.abodeqa.com/tag/how-to-remove-you-are-using-an-unsupported-command-line-flag-ignore-certificate-errors-stability-and-security-will-suffer/).

Instead, you may try the following: (I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112574/selenium-with-chrome-shows-console-window-of-chrome-driver-get-page-complete-e))

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome

...
...

Public Sub key()

  Dim service As OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService = OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()

  Dim chromeOptions As New OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions()
  chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("ignore-certifcate-errors")
  chromeOptions.AddArgument("test-type")

  Dim driver As IWebDriver = New ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions)
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/")

  driver.Quit()

End Sub
```

I added couple lines from my experience running Selenium in C#.

Please provide where `SeleniumWrapper` with its documentation to determine if one can/cannot set `ChromeOptions` for `SeleniumWrapper`.